# How to open Google Drive files in new window

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive

When I open a .gsheet file in my Google Drive, for example, I want this file to open in a new window rather than in a tab in my browser. I can't find a way to make that happen, even though I've set the Google Sheets Chrome app to open in a new window.

Comment: I agree, this is a nuisance in Chrome. What about other browsers?

Comment: Chrome is the default for opening .gsheets files. Not sure if any other browser can do it.

Comment: What happens if you change the default handler for .gsheets? What happens if you uninstall Chrome?